# C# Как выполнить в терминале MacOS команду с аргументами?

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, macos, shell

Допустим, у меня есть функция:

```
public static string ExecuteShellCommand(string cmd, params string[] args) {
    // здесь код...
}
```

Она должна выполнить команду в терминале macOS

(С любым количествома ргументов)

Comment: А сейчас в чём заключается проблема?

Comment: Не понимаю как реализовать механизм исполнения команд.

Comment: Нет, в macOS это не работает.

Comment: Наверное следовало указать, что вы под macOs пишите

Comment: То есть вопрос можно перефразировать так: "Как выполнить команду в терминале в MacOS"? Вы именно это не знаете: что использовать вместо cmd?

Comment: Программа должна работать **только** под macOS или **и** под макос, **и** под Винду, **и** под Линукс?

Answer (score 0):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    FileName = "foo/bar.sh",
    Arguments = "arg1 arg2 arg3",
};

Process proc = new Process() {
    StartInfo = startInfo
};

proc.Start();
```

ответ нашел в гугле по запросу "c# macos terminal command with parameters"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303563/how-to-run-shell-script-with-c-sharp-on-osx